# The multi-part identifier "owt.cardcode" or "t1.cardcode" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query is working fine if I use T3.CardCode = 'AC0109' in second query for inward values but if I use outward query refrence  as (T3.CardCode = owt.CardCode) or (T3.CardCode = t1.CardCode) then it rises error

The multi-part identifier "owt.cardcode" or "t1.cardcode" could not be bound
 Plz help me to solve this problem

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
       owt.CardCode, 
       owt.CardName, 
       owt.DocDate, 
       owt.owtsector,
       owt.owtzone, 
       owt.Dscription, 
       owt.owtrate, 
       owt.owtqty, 
       owt.amount,
       ISNULL(inw.inwqty,0) AS Expr1, 
       ISNULL(inw.inwamount, 0) AS Expr2
FROM (SELECT T1.DocDate, 
             T1.CardCode, 
             T1.CardName, 
             T2.ItemCode, 
             T2.Dscription, 
             T1.U_STTYPE, 
             T1.U_SECTOR AS owtsector, 
             T1.U_ZONE AS owtzone, 
             SUM(T2.LineTotal) AS amount, 
             SUM(T2.Quantity) AS owtqty, 
             T2.CodeBars, 
             T2.Price AS owtrate
      FROM dbo.OWTR AS T1 
          INNER JOIN dbo.WTR1 AS T2 ON T1.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry
      WHERE (T1.DocDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-03-16 00:00:00', 102)) 
        AND (T1.CardCode = N'ac0109') 
        AND (T1.U_STTYPE = N'OUTWARD') 
        AND (T1.U_SECTOR NOT LIKE 'wr%')
      GROUP BY T1.DocDate, 
               T1.CardCode, 
               T1.CardName, 
               T2.ItemCode,
               T2.Dscription, 
               T1.U_STTYPE,  
               T2.Price,
               T1.U_SECTOR, 
               T1.U_ZONE, T2.CodeBars) AS owt 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT T3.DocDate, 
                       T3.CardCode, 
                       T3.CardName, 
                       T3.U_STTYPE, 
                       T4.ItemCode, 
                       T4.Dscription, 
                       SUM(T4.Quantity) AS inwqty, 
                       SUM(T4.LineTotal) AS inwamount
                FROM dbo.OWTR AS T3 
                   INNER JOIN dbo.WTR1 AS T4 ON T3.DocEntry = T4.DocEntry
                WHERE (T3.DocDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-03-16 00:00:00', 102)) 
                  AND (T3.CardCode = ***owt.CardCode***) 
                  AND (T3.U_STTYPE = N' inward ') 
                  AND (T3.U_SECTOR NOT LIKE ' wr % ')
                GROUP BY T3.DocDate, 
                         T3.CardCode, 
                         T3.CardName, 
                         T4.ItemCode, 
                         T4.Dscription, 
                         T3.U_STTYPE) AS inw 
  ON owt.CardCode = inw.CardCode 
 AND owt.DocDate = inw.DocDate
 AND owt.ItemCode = inw.ItemCode
```

Comment: what do you want us to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is within your second subquery (inw) on this line:

```
AND     (T3.CardCode = owt.CardCode)
```

I think it should be:

```
AND     (T3.CardCode = T4.CardCode)
```

**EDIT**

On further thought I don't think you need this predicate at all since it is already contained in the join conditions.

Comment: Infact I will get an input from user ([%1] for t1.cardcode )in query1 and refrence it in second query.

Comment: As I omit this condition my query is working now. I am very thankful to u.